# Please give me some advice on the problem of vimgolf

Tags: vim

https://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/9v006233d72d000000000219

**Start file**

```
#!/bin/bash
a = 5
b = 10
sum = $a + $b
echo $sum

mul = $a * $b
echo $mul
```

**End file**

```
#!/bin/bash
a=5
b=10
sum=$((a + b))
echo $sum

mul=$((a * b))
echo $mul
```

=================================

The keystroke in this problem was 26 but I only get 41.

The way I used it

```
:%s/ = /=/g

:%s/$a/$((a/g

:%s/$b/b))/g
```

I don't know how to reduce keystrokes more. Please give me some advice.

Comment: Isn't vimgolf supposed to be a challenge?

Comment: @romainl well it obviously was a challange, that is why he had to ask =) The question is if vimgolf questions are welcomed on SO? I always like them, because they often pack a lot of knowledge in a single task. But vi.stackexchange would surely be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `/g` means "do the substitution on every match in the line". There is only one match for each pattern so the `/g`s are not necessary:

  ```
  :%s/ = /=<CR>
  :%s/$a/$((a<CR>
  :%s/$b/b))<CR>
  ```

  You are down to 36 keystrokes.

  See `:help :s_g`.
- In this specific case, `$a + $b` can be matched with a single pattern, `$.*b`, so you could fuse the two last substitutions into a single one:

  ```
  :%s/ = /=<CR>
  :%s/$.*b/$((&))<CR>
  ```

  And you are down to 26 keystrokes.

  See `:help s/\&`.